# How to find out about the type of a container in Photos

Tags: applescript, photo

I want to find out, iterating over containers in Photos, if a container is either a folder or an album with this statement:

```
set containerType to class of nextContainer as text
```

When i run this as a script i either get "folder" or "album" as expected.
So my program works fine!

When i run this as an app, as wanted, it gives me something like lPfd or iPal!?
Unfortunately i can not handle this properly.

How would you find out about the type of a Photos container and why is the behaviour so differently?

Comment: The Script Editor loads the names of those terms, but your application doesn't.  You need to use `IPal` or `IPfd` in any comparisons or set the actual text yourself, for example `if class of nextContainer is album then set containerType to "album"`.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood you correctly!? Writing  <if class of nextContainer is album then set containerType to "album"> does not work, as album is only recognized as a variable (showing green in ScriptEditor). And by the way, what is difference to <set containerType to class of nextContainer as text>?

Comment: In a Photo tell statement the term `album` (or `folder`) is a class name, which is what you are getting for `class of nextContainer`.

Comment: but the term album ist not recognized as a class name, it is shown as a variable (in green)!?
The term folder seems to be recognized as a class name, but does not run either?

Comment: Can you edit to show more of your script, including the tell statement?

Comment: Hi,
as you said this, i recognized that my tell statement did not bound the whole part with reading the class! Now, it seems to run as an app also.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, even running in SriptEditor:

```
set containerType to class of nextContainer as text
if containerType is "folder" then
```

runs perfectly!

```
set containerType to class of nextContainer
if containerType is folder then
```

does not run!

What is the difference?